# Transposing wide to long in SAS, without extra columns

Tags: sas

I'd like to transpose a dataset, but SAS insists on adding a new column, if the "by" column
has multiple entries.

So if I run

```
data test;
    input a b $ c $ ; 
datalines;
1  aaa bbb
1  bbb bbb
2  ccc ccc
3  ccc ccc
;
run;

proc transpose data=test;
   by a;
   var b b;
run;
```

I get a table with two columns that looks like this:

```
1   b   aaa bbb
1   c   bbb bbb
2   b   ccc 
2   c   ccc 
3   b   ccc 
3   c   ccc
```

What I'd like with a table that looks like this:

```
1   b   aaa
1   c   bbb
1   b   bbb
1   c   bbb
2   b   ccc 
2   c   ccc 
3   b   ccc 
3   c   ccc
```

So instead of adding columns, for each entry, I want SAS to add rows. Any ideas on how to do this?

Just to be clear, this is a toy example! The dataset I'm working with has more columns.

Comment: I don't think the question is all that clear.  The output you want, for instance, is almost identical to what you started with - it just has an extra variable with 'b' in it.

Comment: That's not what transpose means, is the problem.  Transpose means take rows and makes them columns (or the inverse).  You've already got a long format dataset.  Are you just adding a variable?

Comment: This is a toy example to illustrate a point. The dataset I'm working with has multiple columns.

Comment: The 'toy' example looks like it might have hidden the problem.  Could you revise your example to better highlight the issue?

Comment: I've now changed the toy example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ought to work (using your example code):

```
proc transpose data=test out=test_tran1(rename=(_name_ = old_var));
  by a;
  var b c;
run;

proc transpose data=test_tran1 out=test_tran2(drop=_: rename = (col1=values) where = (not missing(values)));
  by a old_var;
  var col:;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use PROC TRANSPOSE in a single step with a 'mixed' dataset (multiple rows per by group AND multiple columns) to get long.  Transpose only really works well going all one or the other.

Easiest way to get long is usually the data step.

```
data want;
 set test;
 array vars b c;
 do _i = 1 to dim(vars);
  varname = vname(vars[_i]);
  value   = vars[_i];
  output;
 end;
 keep a varname value;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data output;
set test;
array vars {*} b -- c; * define array composed of list of variables from B to C, have to be of same type;

length varname $32;
keep a varname value;

do i=1 to dim(vars);* loop array (list of variables);
    varname= vname(vars(i));* get name of variable that provided value;
    value = vars(i);* get the value of variable;
    output; *output row;
end;
run;
```